# PubNub: How to get conversation history

Tags: pubnub

I have an application used by hundreds of users. Users can start a private chat with each other.
Each one of the users has its own unique id and its own static channel id.

for example:
userId 1 has its private channel id called: *app-private-1*
userId 2 has its private channel id called: *app-private-2*
userId 200 has its private channel id called: *app-private-200*
and so on....

Each one of the users subscribe to its own private channel id to get private messages and also knows the list of all other users private channel ids in order to publish private messages to them.

For example:
when userid 1 want to talk with userid 2 than:
- userId 1 publish message on *app-private-2* channel.
- userId 2 which subscribed to *app-private-2* get the message.
- userId 2 publish back a message to userId 1 on *app-private-1* channel.

The question is how can I get the conversation history chronologically, in the form of who said to whom, in order to present it to the user (I also have section of history in my app).

I can't use the history feature of PubNub because it gives only history of one channel and I will lose the context of who said to whom.
Also, if I will save the messages in my db, it will be a complicate thing to manage and won't solve the issue in a scenario when one side subscribe to channel group and others to only one of the channels.

Any ideas???

Comment: The strategy you have used makes getting a conversation between two users very difficult. To make this simpler, you should create a unique channel for each user-to-user private chat and use the user's private channel for notifications only: *you got a message/invite on channel abc*, for example. What you would have to do it get history on both users' channels and pick out the messages from only those two users. If you didn't store the userid within your message payload, then there is no way to know.

Comment: Furthermore, if you pull history on both channels from a client side app, then the user would see all messages published by other users, assuming the user pulling history has read access to the other users' private channels, but that would be bad. So you would need to call your server to pull history of both channels and sift out the relevant messages of the user-to-user conversation.

Answer (score 1):

### PubNub Channel Topology Decisions

[Channel topology](https://www.pubnub.com/developers/tech/key-concepts/topologies/) is a decision that you need to make early in your app design.

The strategy you have used makes getting a conversation between two users very difficult. To make this simpler, you should create a unique channel for each user-to-user private chat and use the user's private channel for notifications only: you got a message/invite on channel abc, for example.

What you would have to do it get history on both users' channels and pick out the messages from only those two users. If you didn't store the userid within your message payload, then there is no way to know.

### PubNub Function Endpoints

Furthermore, if you pull history on both channels from a client side app, then the user would see all messages published by other users, assuming the user pulling history has read access to the other users' private channels, but that would be bad.

So you would need to call your server (better to implement a [PubNub Function Endpoint](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/announcing-pubnub-functions-and-endpoints/) to do this so you do not have to hit your server) to pull history of both channels and sift out the relevant messages of the user-to-user conversation.

### PubNub ChatEngine For the Win

If it is an option for you, [PubNub ChatEngine will](https://www.pubnub.com/products/chatengine/?utm_source=PayPerClick&utm_medium=Google-Adwords) remove much of the design and implementation details for you, with many plugins (all open source) to handle lots of chat functionality you will need.